# How do you determine the smallest and largest positive integer inputs when the user can give as many inputs as they want in c?

Tags: c, integer

Hi I'm a beginner learning to write c and I was wondering how you would write a code that promts you to give a positive integer and ends once you've entered 0 and the previous numbers before 0 is at least 2 positive integers. The program then determines the largest positive integer input and smallest integer input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int integer=0, largest_int, smallest_int;

    while (integer) {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
        scanf("%d", &integer);
        if (integer = 0) {
            while (integer<=0) {
                printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
                scanf("%d", &integer);
                    if (integer>0) {
                        printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
                        scanf("%d", &integer);

                        if (integer>0) {
                            printf("the largest integer is.....and the smallest integer is......");printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
                            scanf("%d", &integer);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

at first I tried to use  do/while loop but it didn't work at all.

I'm also onfused with how the compiler is reading the loops when there's an if ese statment in the loop.

Here's what I was thinking:
I thought about having the "Enter positive integer" ask repetitivly until you input a two positive numbers. Then I'd have the program check if the next input is equal to zero if it doesn;t then it continues the loop again. If the user does input at least two positive integers and then a zero the loop breaks and I print out the greatest int and smallest int. What also confuses me is how you would be able to filter through all the user's inputs and determine these values because I could keep entering a integers 100000000000000000000 times and out of all those times how would I know?

Comment: the user is able to input as many integers as they want the there is not maximum amount of integers

Comment: Your code does virtually nothing since you have initialized integer to 0 and using it in the while loop

Comment: Is a switch statement of for loop a better choice?

Comment: clarification: at least positive consecutive integers before the zero

Answer (score 1):

As this seems to be homework, some points for you to ponder.

Your `while (integer)` is never executed as you initialize `integer` to zero just before it. So what you have really is `while(0)`, and nothing inside the loop is executed. You could replace it by a `do { ... } while(condition)` but I'd rather keep the kind of current loop and add an extra input reading before the loop (the reason is to initialize variables for maximum and minimum finding -- see below).

Add a variable, say `NPos` to count how many of the last entries where a positive integer. initialize it to zero. Each time a number is entered, if it is positive increase the value of `NPos`. Otherwise set it to zero (this can be tricky as if the entry is zero it may also mean stop execution instead of reset `NPos`). When the number entered is 0, check that `NPos` is at least 2 and, if so, stop.

For finding extreme values, create two variables (`max` and `min`) and initialize them to the first user input. Then, at each valid input, i. e., not an input meaning end of execution, check whether the value is greater than `max` or less than`min`. If so, replace `max` or `min` by the input.

These are the greater lines of the algorithm. The implementation is up to you.

A final note: I do not like to name a value `integer`, but that is maybe just me.

Comment: +1 to allow arbitrary many inputs NPos should be limited: `NPos = min(2, NPos);`. Also [I've interpreted the "at least 2 positive integers" requirement differently](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12862874/4279) (it is not clear that they should be consecutive)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution but some coding errors in your code:

your code will not work first as follows

```
 int integer=0, largest_int, smallest_int;

            while (integer) {
                    ........
                            }
```

Here integer is 0 and you are giving this in while which will comes out at the first check.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/McSOL)

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int integer, largest_int = INT_MIN, smallest_int = INT_MAX;
  int count_positive = 0;

  for ( ; ; ) {
    printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
    scanf("%d", &integer); //XXX add error handling
    if (integer == 0 && count_positive > 1) 
      break;
    else if (integer > 0) {
      count_positive = count_positive > 1 ? 2 : count_positive + 1;
      if (largest_int < integer)
        largest_int = integer;
      if (smallest_int > integer)
        smallest_int = integer;
    }
  }
  printf("%d %d\n", smallest_int, largest_int);
  return 0;
}
```

if "at least 2 positive integers" requirement means that they should be consecutive then reset count_positive to zero when you've encountered an integer less than or equal to zero. Add to the loop:

```
else if (integer <= 0) 
  count_positive = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    int integer, largest_int=INT_MIN, smallest_int=INT_MAX;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &integer);
        if (integer < 0)
        continue;
        else if (integer == 0)
        break;
        else
        {
            if (integer > largest_int)
            largest_int = integer;
            if (integer < smallest_int)
            smallest_int = integer;
        }
    } while(1);

    printf("Largest integer is %d\nSmallest integer is %d", largest_int, smallest_int);
}
```